# How to make top and bottom of div transparent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am making a div with a content longer than what I want to view in height, so I used a height of 20em, and made overflow:scroll. This work great, but I want to add some effect to it.

How can I do so the top and bottom 50px have a opacity of 0.7? so it gets a effect when the content is scrolled "away".

Thanks!

```
<div>
<ul>
   <li>long list here</li>
   <li>long list here</li>
   <li>long list here</li>
   <li>long list here</li>

</ul>
```

Style:

```
height:25em;
overflow:scroll;
```

Comment: can we see your codes?

Comment: This is not easy to do with CSS or even jQuery. What do you have so far? Or were you expecting us to write it for you?? ;)

Comment: Please code for help you.

Comment: Its not easy job to do with css no! But the answer bellow worked for me! Sorry that I didn't post cod at first, but lot of code, and time is 02:31 here. Anyway! @Oriol answer helped a lot so thanks!

Comment: It may work for you, but it won't work on IE7. If you are on some commercial website, than forget about these pseudo elements. Also, correct syntax to write pseudo elements is double-colon (such as `::before`), but than it won't work on IE8, too. On the other hand, you can be sure some 90% of visitors will see it correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/s27v3/1/)

### DEMO:

```css
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
#wrapper:before, #wrapper:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 30px; /* Height of the effect */
}
#wrapper:before {
    top: 0;
    /* Use your background color, assuming white: */
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(255,255,255,0));
}
#wrapper:after {
    bottom: 0;
    /* Use your background color, assuming white: */
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(255,255,255,0));
}
#mydiv {
    background: red;
    height: 20em;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 0 solid transparent;
    border-width: 10px 0; /* 10px to be able to read first and last lines */
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="mydiv">
        Your content
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add two layers at top and bottom, note it will cover your content so I suggest it takes no more than 20px. Here is an example with transparent covers, but you can use nice PNG gradient instead:

```css
.fixed_height {
  position: relative;
}
.fixed_height_content {
  padding: 20px 0;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.cover_top {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  opacity: .3;
}
.cover_bottom {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  opacity: .3;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Opacity</title>

  <style type="text/css">

  </style>

</head>
<body>

  <div class="fixed_height">

    <div class="fixed_height_content">
      <p>Some content<br />more<br />more<br />more<br />more</p>
      <p>Some content<br />more<br />more<br />more<br />more</p>
      <p>Some content<br />more<br />more<br />more<br />more</p>
      <p>Some content<br />more<br />more<br />more<br />more</p>
    </div>

    <div class="cover_top"></div>
    <div class="cover_bottom"></div>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may like this. Try this one.

```
<style>    
#boxBorder {
    height: 3em;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
#boxBorder:hover {
height: 5em;
overflow: hidden;
}
#boxBorder:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px; 
    bottom: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(256,256,256,0));   
}
</style>
```

and my div is like

```
<div id="boxBorder">
    Vis meis ipsum cu, est ad modus facilis, ut est modus alienum consulatu. Mel ut primis dissentias. Doming omittam necessitatibus eam ei, simul vocibus complectitur at eam. Aliquid dolorem laboramus pri et. Porro utroque facilis ex has, pro eripuit ullamcorper te, an audiam civibus voluptaria mei.

    Consul iuvaret te eam. Eu usu modus nonumy nostrud, his ne facilis maiestatis. Nec clita nonumes ea, solet noluisse vix cu. Te vel altera verterem sapientem, quo corrumpit theophrastus ne.
    Quo iusto exerci assentior cu, ius erat velit timeam ea. Te modo offendit consectetuer has, id ius utamur quaerendum. Ut choro neglegentur nec, ea iusto feugait est. Feugait reprimique mel id, mel ad indoctum definitionem, nostrum apeirian ad pro.
```

an discere delenit.